# Checking Username and Password to match in SQLIte

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I check if the Username and Password would be the same as the Username and Password in the Database.

AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void) readLoginFromDatabase {
// Setup the database object
sqlite3 *database;

// Init the Array
lo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "Select * from Login";
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            // Read the data from the result row
            NSString *aLoginName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];
            NSString *aLoginPass = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];
            NSString *aLoginAccess = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];

            // Create a new object with the data from the database
            Login *los = [[Login alloc] initWithName:aLoginName pass:aLoginPass access:aLoginAccess];

            // Add the object to the Array
            [lo addObject:los];
        }
    }
    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
-(IBAction)buttonWasClicked:(id)sender
{
if ((userText.text != logins.loginUser) && (passText.text != logins.loginPass))
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Username/Password is incorrect!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show]; 
}
else
{
     StudentViewController *studentView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"studentView"];
    [studentView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; 

    [self presentViewController:studentView animated:YES completion:nil];
}   

if (userText.text != logins.loginUser)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Username is incorrect!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
}

if (passText.text != logins.loginPass)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Password is incorrect!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];
} 
}
```

Even when the Username and Password I type is exactly the same as in the database, it would still show me the error message instead of displaying the next view.

Comment: Don't you want to 1. hash your passwords; 2. use column 0, 1 and 2 instead of 1, 2 and 3; 3. learn C and read NSString's docs?

Comment: For Static NSStrings you can just Use @"TEXT" you do not have to alloc and init them.

Comment: Make your condition correct....and debug it,,,

Comment: @H2CO3 my password is already hash. I can't use column 0,1 and 2 as my 0 is my primary key.

Comment: @jussi how do i just use @"TEXT" and do not alloc and init them?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check NSStrings in objective-c with

```
isEqualToString
```

For your example:

```
if (![userText.text isEqualToString:logins.loginUser])
```

Check: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/isEqualToString:

Comment: It is showing me the alert view when i type the correct username and wrong username.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isEqualToString method to check that two string is equal....

```
if ([userText.text isEqualToString:logins.loginUser])
```

and apply condition like this

```
-(IBAction)buttonWasClicked:(id)sender
{
    Login *logins = nil;
    logins= [lo objectAtIndexPath:0];

    if ([userText.text  isEqualToString:logins.loginUser] && [passText.text isEqualToString:logins.loginPass])
    {
        StudentViewController *studentView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"studentView"];
        [studentView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve]; 

        [self presentViewController:studentView animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else if (![userText.text  isEqualToString:logins.loginUser])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Username is incorrect!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
    else if (![passText.text  isEqualToString:logins.loginPass])
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Password is incorrect!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your Username/Password is incorrect!"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

        [alert show]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: i tired and it is not showing me any alert view when i type the wrong username.

Comment: i tried it already. When i type in the correct username and password, it still show me the alert view.

Comment: hey now check that what value you are getting from dataBase and which value are you giving....

Comment: I placed breakpoint and tried it out. I getting nothing at `logins.loginUser`.

Comment: just chk are you getting value from    NSString *aLoginName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

Comment: I am getting value from `NSString *aLoginName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)]; ` and it is able to be stored in the array.

Comment: From `NSString *aLoginName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];` it showed me the data that i previously stored in the database. but for `(logins.loginUser) i am getting 0.

Comment: I only have 2 records inside and I'm getting both of it.

Comment: hi just chk my answer again....make object of Login class and insert array object(like your array is lo)...and call the logins.name to check...

Comment: I tried and tried to rearrange the codes but it still wouldn't read from the database.

Comment: ok then just save your database record in dictionary and array...and then use this array....or you can send me ur code...i will chk....

Comment: Please don't use the comments section as an interactive debug session.